# Maintain height of plot in R

Tags: r, plot, height, bar-chart

I'm trying to keep my barplot at a particular height so that if the window is resized the height is maintained. i.e. I want my barplot to always be narrow and long. Is this possible?

I've tried

```
par(pty="s")
```

but that just maintains the aspect ratio of both x and y coordinates and makes it always a box.

Here is what I'd like my barplot to always look like:

[image]

And heres what I'd like to avoid:

[image]

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `pin` parameter, see [`?par`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/graphics/html/par.html):

> `pin`
>
> The current plot dimensions, (width, height), in inches.

Comment: Wicked! Thanks. I guess theres no way of making it so that you only vary the width when you resize.

Comment: Oh and how would you reset this value back to its default? i.e. maximize plot size in the space

Comment: @by0 In playing around with it (in Windows R GUI), it seems to reset to the default every time the plot window is closed. This may be different on other platforms, though.